# Change value of dropdown list based on last 2 variables in a textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a textfield which meant for car registration numbers to be entered in. The registration is based on years and the format is `GT 74454 12`, the last digit `12` representing the year `2012` meaning the car was register in `2012`. I want a script that will autodected the last two digits and affect the value of the dropdown list.

For example if the year range from `09 - 12` the value of the dropdown should be Red. If it ranges from `13 - 16`, the value of the dropdown should change to Blue.

HTML

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <label for="car_no"></label>
  <input type="text" name="car_no" id="car_no" />
  <label for="select"></label>
  <select name="select" id="select">
    <option>Color Code</option>
    <option>Red</option>
    <option>Blue</option>
    <option>White</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y18c2hzo/

```
EDIT
there are some registrations that comes in a different format too which goes like this "GT 74454 X". How do i make the script autodect if the last digit is an alphabet the value shoud change to white
```

Comment: Can you please post the js that you've tried so far?

Comment: What should happen for those cars registered before 2009 and/or don't fit this format?

Comment: @DavidThomas, that's a great suggestion i've editted the post

Comment: And yet you still haven't demonstrated any attempts at, or explained your difficulties/problems in, solving this yourself; "*I want…*" is not a question, it's a demand; or, at best, a statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this below code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#car_no").change(function(){
  var value= $(this).val(),
      year = value.split(" ")[2];
  if(year >=9 && year<=12)
   $("#select").val("Red")
    if(year >=13 && year<=16)
   $("#select").val("Blue")
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <label for="car_no">car number</label>
  <input type="text" name="car_no" id="car_no" />
  <label for="select"></label>
  <select name="select" id="select">
    <option>Color Code</option>
    <option>Red</option>
    <option>Blue</option>
    <option>White</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks, the script works,there are does that comes in a different format too which goes like this "GT 74454 X". How do i make the script autodect if the last digit is an alphabet the value should change to white

Comment: Check this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/ooz0wLr3/. Using **isNaN()** method you can check whether the value is number or not.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a simple example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/y18c2hzo/1/).

```
$('#car_no').keyup(function (event) {
    var value = $(event.target).val();
    var year = parseInt(value.trim().substr(-2), 10);
    if (year >= 9 && year <= 12) {
        $('#select').val('Red');
    } else if (year >= 13 && year <= 16) {
        $('#select').val('Blue');
    }
});
```

This code simply detects keyup events on your text input and retrieves its value. The year is determined by removing any whitespace and taking the last two digits of the string and converting it to an integer. Then you can compare the values of the year and adjust the value of the combobox accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
  alert( this.value ); // or $(this).val()
  if(your condition){
  $("select").css("background-color", "red");
  }else if (your condition){
  ///your codes
  }
});
```